# regular expression match issue in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

For input string, want to match text which starts with `{(P)` and ends with `(P)}`, and I just want to match the parts in the middle. Wondering if we can write one regular expression to resolve this issue?

For example, in the following example, for the input string, I want to retrieve *hello world* part. Using Python 2.7.

```
python {(P)hello world(P)} java
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `{\(P\)(.*)\(P\)}`, and use parenthesis in the pattern to capture everything between `{(P)` and `(P)}`:

```
import re
re.findall(r'{\(P\)(.*)\(P\)}', "python {(P)hello world(P)} java")

# ['hello world']
```

`.*` also matches unicode characters, for example:

```
import re
str1 = "python {(P)£1,073,142.68(P)} java"
str2 = re.findall(r'{\(P\)(.*)\(P\)}', str1)[0]

str2
# '\xc2\xa31,073,142.68'

print str2
# £1,073,142.68
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom, vote up for your solution. I found if between two `(P)`, there are ASCII, it could be output successfully. But if in the middle there are unicode character, the output (I use `print re.findall(r'{\(P\)(.*)\(P\)}', "python {(P)hello world(P)} java")` to output) will be weird, like `['\xe5\x8e\]`, any ideas to convert them back to unicode character when using print to output?

Comment: The unicode characters are captured the same way as ASCII characters. You just need to print them nicely to see what actually are. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Cool Psidom, vote up, looking forward to your reply.

Comment: You will need to print each element in the list instead of printing the whole list to see them as usual. `re.findall` return a list of all matches.

Comment: Got it, thanks Psidom, vote up and will do some further testing and mark your reply as answer.

Comment: Hi Psidom, your solution works quite well for me, mark your reply as answer.

Comment: I appreciate it. Glad it helps :)

Comment: Sure, glad you are patient for helping me. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use positive look-arounds to ensure that it only matches if the text is preceded and followed by the start and end tags.  For instance, you could use this pattern:

```
(?<={\(P\)).*?(?=\(P\)})
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA9uP2/1).

- `(?<={\(P\))` - Look-behind expression stating that a match must be preceded by `{(P)`.
- `.*?` - Matches all text between the start and end tags.  The `?` makes the star lazy (i.e. non-greedy).  That means it will match as little as possible.
- `(?=\(P\)})` - Look-ahead expression stating that a match must be followed by `(P)}`.

For what it's worth, lazy patterns are technically less efficient, so if you know that there will be no `(` characters in the match, it would be better to use a negative character class:

```
(?<={\(P\))[^(]*(?=\(P\)})
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, vote up. Why you need to begin with `?` sign?

Comment: That's the syntax for look-arounds.  `(?<= ... )` creates a positive look-behind.  `(?= ... )` creates a positive look-ahead.  By using look-around expressions, you can state that certain things must be present before or after the match without actually including them in the match.

Comment: Cool, thanks Steve, vote up. I found if between two `(P)`, there are ASCII, it could be output successfully. But if in the middle there are unicode character, the output (I use `print re.findall(r'(?<={\(P\)).*?(?=\(P\)})', utf-8-string-to-pass)` to output) will be weird, like `['\xe5\x8e\]`, any ideas to convert them back to unicode character when using print to output?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this without regular expressions:

```
s = 'python {(P)hello world(P)} java'
r = s.split('(P)')[1]
print(r)
# 'hello world'
```

Comment: What about the `{` and `}` requirements?! Your code work for the **example** but not answer the question

Comment: Yes, I have the same feeling of @OhadEytan, vote up.

Comment: Thanks Moses for the reply and vote up, if you could address the issue raised by @OhadEytan, it will be great.